# Why are my calculations not correct?

Tags: java, arrays, csv, average

My program is reading a CSV and inputting the data into an Array. Once the data has been stored into an array, I would like to modify the data in order to find certain calculations, such as Average, max number and the minimum number.

I simply can not see where I am going wrong...I am sure it is something simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class calculation {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    double year[] = new double [804];
    double month[] = new double [804];
    double tmax[] = new double [804];
    double tmin[] = new double [804];
    double af[] = new double [804];
    double rain[] = new double [804];
    double sun[] = new double [804];
    double tavg[] = new double[804];
    double sumYear = 0;
    double sumMonth = 0;
    double sumTmin = 0;
    double sumTmax = 0;
    double sumRain = 0;
    double sumAF = 0;
    double sumSun = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    //CREATE BUFFERED READER TO READ DATA           
    try {
        BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.csv"));
        String line="";
        //Implement code here
        int index=0;

        //CREATE WHILE LOOP TO READ DATA LINE BY LINE
        while((line = file.readLine()) != null) {
            //Print data to console line by line to ensure it reads data properly
            System.out.println(line);
            //we need to apply split method
            String[] splits = line.split(","); //This will have total of 7 values 

            year[index] = Double.parseDouble(splits[0]);
            month [index] = Double.parseDouble(splits[1]);
            tmax [index] = Double.parseDouble(splits[2]);
            tmin [index] = Double.parseDouble(splits[3]);
            af [index] = Double.parseDouble(splits[4]);
            rain [index] = Double.parseDouble(splits[5]);
            sun [index] = Double.parseDouble(splits[6]);

            sumYear += year[0];
            sumMonth += month[1];
            sumTmax += tmax[2];
            sumTmin += tmin[3];
            sumAF+= af[4];
            sumRain += rain[5];
            sumSun+= sun[6];


            counter++;
            index++;


    }           } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    //now print averages
    double avgTmax = sumTmax/counter;
    double avgTmin = sumTmin/counter;
    double avgFrost = sumAF/counter;
    double avgRain = sumRain/counter;
    double avgSun = sumSun/counter;
    System.out.println("Average: Maximum Temp: " + avgTmax);
    System.out.println("Average: Minimum Temp: " + avgTmin);
    System.out.println("Average: Rain: " + avgRain);
    System.out.println("Average: Frost: " + avgFrost);
    System.out.println("Average: Sun: " + avgSun);


    }   

}
```

Comment: You need to say what is wrong

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: *FYI:* Java is an Object-Oriented language. Use it. Don't create parallel arrays. Instead, create a class with your 8 `double` fields, then create a *single* array of those objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
sumYear += year[0];
sumMonth += month[1];
sumTmax += tmax[2];
sumTmin += tmin[3];
sumAF += af[4];
sumRain += rain[5];
sumSun += sun[6];
```

must be

```
sumYear += year[index];
sumMonth += month[index];
sumTmax += tmax[index];
sumTmin += tmin[index];
sumAF += af[index];
sumRain += rain[index];
sumSun += sun[index];
```

You have read a line consisting of values separated by comma, split it and stored the *individual* values (`splits[0]`,`splits[1]`..`splits[6]`) into the corresponding arrays. To read them back, you need to use the same `index` you have written to.

**EDIT:**

Unless you have a need to store the actual values, you can get rid of the arrays and can simply calculate the running sum as `sumYear += Double.parseDouble(splits[0]);` (similarly for all)

Comment: It doesn;t have to be that: the arrays aren't necessary. Simply `sumYear += Double.parseDouble(splits[0]);` would work.

Comment: @AndyTurner Absolutely. I'm not sure if the OP has something else to do with the arrays.